# SQL Picking the row with the highest value for each unique ID

Tags: sql-server

EDITTED 18/02/2021

*Here is the information*

**Columns Description**

1. orderNumber: A string that is exactly 10 characters long. The first is a letter and last character is either A, G, H, L. The characters in between are digits.
2. datetimeVisit: A date and time where the date cannot be later than the current date, and the time is between 11am to 2.59pm and between 5pm to 9.59pm.
3. tableNumber A whole number that is between 1 and 10.
4. numPax: A non-negative whole number.
5. orderItemNo: A whole number
6. dishId: An auto-generated value starting with 1 and an increment of 1 size A value that is either small, medium, large, standard price A non-negative decimal value, with default value 9.90
7. dishName: A value that is at most 30 characters long
8. size: A value that is either small, medium, large, standard
9. price: A non-negative decimal value, with default value 9.90
10. dishName: A value that is at most 30 characters long

**Foreign key constraints**

- Minimum cardinality between FoodOrder and OrderItem is 1:N, M:M with delete and update cascaded.
- Minimum cardinality between MenuItemSize and OrderItem is 1:N, M:O with delete
  disallowed and update cascaded.
- Minimum cardinality between MenuItem and MenuItemSize is 1:N, M:M with delete and
  update disallowed.

**Question:**

- Create a view, OrderSummary with the details that includes a timeslot, the
  number of items ordered, the total cost of the items ordered, a miscellaneous
  charge which is $2.50 per customer, and the total amount which is the sum of
  the item cost and the miscellaneous charge. Display the rows in your view.

```
CREATE VIEW ORDERSUMMARY AS
    SELECT DISTINCT FO.orderNumber, FO.datetimeVisit, FO.tableNumber, FO.numPax,
        CASE
            WHEN CAST(datetimeVisit AS TIME) BETWEEN '11:00:00' AND '11:30:00' THEN '11:00 to 11.30'
            WHEN CAST(datetimeVisit AS TIME) BETWEEN '11:31:00' AND '11:59:00' THEN '11:31 to 11.59'
            WHEN CAST(datetimeVisit AS TIME) BETWEEN '12:00:00' AND '12:30:00' THEN '12:00 to 12.30'
            WHEN CAST(datetimeVisit AS TIME) BETWEEN '12:31:00' AND '12:59:00' THEN '12:31 to 12.59'
            WHEN CAST(datetimeVisit AS TIME) BETWEEN '13:00:00' AND '13:30:00' THEN '13:00 to 13:30'
            WHEN CAST(datetimeVisit AS TIME) BETWEEN '13:31:00' AND '13:59:00' THEN '13:31 to 13:59'
            WHEN CAST(datetimeVisit AS TIME) BETWEEN '14:00:00' AND '14:59:00' THEN '14:00 to 14.30'
            WHEN CAST(datetimeVisit AS TIME) BETWEEN '14:31:00' AND '14:59:00' THEN '14:31 to 14.59'
            WHEN CAST(datetimeVisit AS TIME) BETWEEN '17:00:00' AND '17:30:00' THEN '17:00 to 17.30'
            WHEN CAST(datetimeVisit AS TIME) BETWEEN '17:31:00' AND '17:59:00' THEN '17:31 to 17.59'
            WHEN CAST(datetimeVisit AS TIME) BETWEEN '18:00:00' AND '18:30:00' THEN '18:00 to 18.30'
            WHEN CAST(datetimeVisit AS TIME) BETWEEN '18:31:00' AND '18:59:00' THEN '18:31 to 18.59'
            WHEN CAST(datetimeVisit AS TIME) BETWEEN '19:00:00' AND '19:30:00' THEN '19:00 to 19.30'
            WHEN CAST(datetimeVisit AS TIME) BETWEEN '19:31:00' AND '19:59:00' THEN '19:31 to 19.59'
            WHEN CAST(datetimeVisit AS TIME) BETWEEN '20:00:00' AND '20:30:00' THEN '20:00 to 20.30'
            WHEN CAST(datetimeVisit AS TIME) BETWEEN '20:31:00' AND '20:59:00' THEN '20:31 to 20.59'
            WHEN CAST(datetimeVisit AS TIME) BETWEEN '21:00:00' AND '21:30:00' THEN '21:00 to 21.30'
            WHEN CAST(datetimeVisit AS TIME) BETWEEN '21:31:00' AND '21:59:00' THEN '21:31 to 21.59'
            WHEN CAST(datetimeVisit AS TIME) BETWEEN '22:00:00' AND '22:30:00' THEN '22:00 to 22.30'
            WHEN CAST(datetimeVisit AS TIME) BETWEEN '22:31:00' AND '22:59:00' THEN '22:31 to 22.59'
            ELSE 'Invalid timeslot' 
            END AS timeslot,
    OI.orderItemNo AS NumberOfItems, OI.orderItemNo*price AS FoodAmount, 2.50*numPax AS MiscCharge, (OI.orderItemNo*price + 2.50*numPax) AS TotalAmount
    FROM FOODORDER AS FO
    LEFT JOIN ORDERITEM AS OI
    ON FO.orderNumber = OI.orderNumber
    LEFT JOIN MENUITEMSIZE AS MIS
    ON MIS.dishID = OI.dishID AND MIS.size = OI.size
```

How can I get only one row from each orderNumber with the highest orderItemNo?

Comment: Sorry its my first time here! Hope to have my query solved! Thanks

Comment: In your select you have selected orderNumber two times ? Why ? Also, what is this: 'WHERE FO.orderNumber = FO.orderNumber' ?

Comment: Oops! I have that removed! I have replaced one of the SELECTED orderNumber to orderItemNo.

Comment: Helo @DonHo, I am sorry but I do not see that. You need to edit your question. Click edit option under your question and change the text in your question...

Comment: @VBoka hi! I have made the amendments + added more info of the question! Many thanks in advanced

Answer (score 0):

I have created a more simple example and I will try to explain to you what is it you need to do. Here is the code:

```
SELECT T1.orderNumber
       , MAX(orderItemNo)
       , CASE WHEN CAST(datetimeVisit AS TIME) BETWEEN '11:00:00' AND '11:30:00' THEN '11:00 to 11.30'
            WHEN CAST(datetimeVisit AS TIME) BETWEEN '11:31:00' AND '11:59:00' THEN '11:31 to 11.59'
            WHEN CAST(datetimeVisit AS TIME) BETWEEN '12:00:00' AND '12:30:00' THEN '12:00 to 12.30'
            WHEN CAST(datetimeVisit AS TIME) BETWEEN '12:31:00' AND '12:59:00' THEN '12:31 to 12.59'
            WHEN CAST(datetimeVisit AS TIME) BETWEEN '13:00:00' AND '13:30:00' THEN '13:00 to 13:30'
            WHEN CAST(datetimeVisit AS TIME) BETWEEN '13:31:00' AND '13:59:00' THEN '13:31 to 13:59'
            WHEN CAST(datetimeVisit AS TIME) BETWEEN '14:00:00' AND '14:59:00' THEN '14:00 to 14.30'
            WHEN CAST(datetimeVisit AS TIME) BETWEEN '14:31:00' AND '14:59:00' THEN '14:31 to 14.59'
            WHEN CAST(datetimeVisit AS TIME) BETWEEN '17:00:00' AND '17:30:00' THEN '17:00 to 17.30'
            WHEN CAST(datetimeVisit AS TIME) BETWEEN '17:31:00' AND '17:59:00' THEN '17:31 to 17.59'
            WHEN CAST(datetimeVisit AS TIME) BETWEEN '18:00:00' AND '18:30:00' THEN '18:00 to 18.30'
            WHEN CAST(datetimeVisit AS TIME) BETWEEN '18:31:00' AND '18:59:00' THEN '18:31 to 18.59'
            WHEN CAST(datetimeVisit AS TIME) BETWEEN '19:00:00' AND '19:30:00' THEN '19:00 to 19.30'
            WHEN CAST(datetimeVisit AS TIME) BETWEEN '19:31:00' AND '19:59:00' THEN '19:31 to 19.59'
            WHEN CAST(datetimeVisit AS TIME) BETWEEN '20:00:00' AND '20:30:00' THEN '20:00 to 20.30'
            WHEN CAST(datetimeVisit AS TIME) BETWEEN '20:31:00' AND '20:59:00' THEN '20:31 to 20.59'
            WHEN CAST(datetimeVisit AS TIME) BETWEEN '21:00:00' AND '21:30:00' THEN '21:00 to 21.30'
            WHEN CAST(datetimeVisit AS TIME) BETWEEN '21:31:00' AND '21:59:00' THEN '21:31 to 21.59'
            WHEN CAST(datetimeVisit AS TIME) BETWEEN '22:00:00' AND '22:30:00' THEN '22:00 to 22.30'
            WHEN CAST(datetimeVisit AS TIME) BETWEEN '22:31:00' AND '22:59:00' THEN '22:31 to 22.59'
            ELSE 'Invalid timeslot' 
         END timeslot
FROM T1
LEFT JOIN T2 ON T1.orderNumber = T2.orderNumber
GROUP BY T1.orderNumber, T2.datetimeVisit
ORDER BY T1.orderNumber;
```

Here is a demo:
[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=995430eb6113306795e73d7cbaef5dea)

You need to select 'max(orderItemNo)' for every orderNumber. That is why I have added 'max(orderItemNo)' in the select clause of my code.

After you have selected max(orderItemNo) you need to add group by clause where you will add all the columns you have selected. In my example I had to add orderNumber and datetimeVisit in my group by clause.

After the group by clause I have added also a order by clause just to represent the result of the query in a more clear way.

Comment: Hello @DonHo does my answer help you ?